# How to lay laminate flooring against an exterior threshold

Tags: laminate-floor

I’m installing laminate flooring in my house and just got to my front door and realized the threshold won’t have molding on it. How is this normally handled? The transition pieces are only for interior doorways.

Comment: It depends on the profile of your threshold. Some have a tall vertical against which you can install an L molding. Please post photos from several angles.

Comment: What edge of the laminate is at the threshold, the long edge, a collection of cut ends (short edges), or a long edge ripped to fit the remaining gap?

Comment: For what it's worth I ended up cutting custom transition pieces out of oak.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a piece of shoe moulding is used to cover a small gap against a threshold. I prefer my rips out of sight, so when possible, I start my floors at the front of the house and put my rips at the back of the house.

A general rule for installing any type of hardwood flooring is to start on the longest exterior wall.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get a good flexible and durable caulk that can expand and retract with the flooring and use that to fill the gap between the flooring and the threshold.

Alternatively I think I've heard of people using wood filler instead but if you choose this route make sure it can expand and retract with the flooring.

Comment: Caulk and putty are a last resort, IMO. They don't often look professional.

Comment: Depending on the width and finishing you can make it as professional looking as you want. Do remember though that a solid filler will likely crack when (not if) the wood expands and contracts with changing moisture levels.